# How do I remove excess whitespace in an HTML file? (And only excess whitespace)

Tags: html, tidy, command-line-tool

I have a horrible, ugly HTML file that was spat out by a form generator and slightly modified to look nice. This HTML file needs to be translated, so I hooked up some scripts using po4a and csv2po, and that all works fairly well except for one thing: some of the base strings in our translation templates are surrounded by whitespace, and the translators get rather confused.

The other thing is I have this working with a Makefile (because that generated form is updated quite frequently and I'm a nerd). I'd like to keep it that way because it's nice for my workflow. So, I need a command line tool.

I'm really looking for the simplest solution in this case, so I ran the HTML file through [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/), and that removes the weird whitespace quite competently. However, it does a lot of stuff I don't need. It messes with the doctype (and it doesn't support an html5 doctype), and I've ended up with a really crazy command line just to get it to not mangle things. It is not very pleasant.

All I really want is a command line tool (not an online one) whose single goal in life is to look at my HTML file and format it nicely. Ideally not a "compressor" thing, but if that's the only option, suggestions would be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Stick it in an ide or text editor like notepad++ or net beans and hit the "format code" button which is available in nearly every ide?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is still being developed, but would [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) do the trick?

Comment: @XenElement I'm not sure how I missed that, ha.

Comment: No problem - downvote was kind of harsh though - I was just trying to make sure the better answer stayed at the top.

Comment: @XenElement - +1 for the above answer ;)